# How to return response within the interceptor in CXF

Tags: java, cxf

I have a web service and I have implemented a few interceptors, the aim of one is to check if we have an identical request for that particular request and response. If we have that request I will need to return an existing response in DB from the interceptor.

I am able to create a response as SOAPMessage but cannot return a response. Note that I don't want to throw Fault, I need to return directly to the client.
I have tried `message.getExchange().put(SOAPMessage.class, (SOAPMessage) soapMessage);` that blocks the following interceptors but service still gets invoked.

And I could not use Conduit since it requires Message object instead of SOAPMessage. There is an example in https://gist.github.com/palesz/3438143#file-basicauthauthorizationinterceptor-java

```
            SOAPMessage soapMessage =  messageFactory.createMessage();
            soapMessage.getSOAPPart().setContent((Source)  new StreamSource(new StringReader(previousResponseString)));
            soapMessage.saveChanges();
            message.getExchange().put(SOAPMessage.class, (SOAPMessage) soapMessage);
```

Here the `previousResponseString` is a string that is a proper xml.

Is there a way to return the response from the interceptor?

```
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
public class DummyInInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
    public DummyInInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.USER_PROTOCOL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {

   /*     Map< String, String> is =  soapMessage.getEnvelopeNs();
        is.get("end");*/
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = message.getContent(SOAPMessage.class);

        try{
            // Extracting the incoming soap message.
            SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
            SOAPBody soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();

            // Getting conversationId to compare with the older requests
            String conversationID =  soapHeader.getElementsByTagName("conversationID").item(0).getTextContent();
            Node operationRequest = (Node) soapBody.getFirstChild();
            String operationName = operationRequest.getNextSibling().getLocalName();

            LogService logService = (LogService) ApplicationContextConfig.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getBean("logService");
            String previousResponseString = logService.getRequestForConversationId(conversationID);
            Document previousResponse =  loadXMLString(previousResponseString);
            String previousResponseCode = previousResponse.getElementsByTagName("responseCode").item(0).getTextContent();


            if(previousResponse == null){
                // Logic will go here
            }
            if(Integer.parseInt(previousResponseCode) == 100){
                //send previous response

            }


            //message.getExchange().put(SOAPMessage.class, (SOAPMessage) previousResponse);

            String replacedContent = previousResponseString.replace("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","http://schemas.xmlenv.org/env/envelope/");
            MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = new MimeHeaders();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(previousResponseString.replace("soap","env").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            mimeHeaders.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
            SOAPMessage soapMessage1 =  messageFactory.createMessage();
            soapMessage1.getSOAPPart().setContent((Source)  new StreamSource(new StringReader(previousResponseString)));
            soapMessage1.saveChanges();

            message.getExchange().put(SOAPMessage.class, (SOAPMessage) soapMessage1);

        }catch (SOAPException e ){
            throw new Fault(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Here is how I implemented the interceptors

```
@javax.jws.WebService(
        serviceName = "MyService",
        portName = "MyServicePort",
        targetNamespace = "http://xxx/",
        wsdlLocation = "classpath:MyService.wsdl.wsdl",
        endpointInterface = "xxx")
@InInterceptors(interceptors ={"packagename.LogInInterceptor",
        "org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor",
        "packagename.DummyInInterceptor"})
@OutInterceptors(interceptors = "packagename.LogOutInterceptor")
@Slf4j
public class MyServicePortImpl implements MyService{
```

For security reasons I have put "xxx" in some of the fields. Please ignore unnecasary fields.

Please Note: I want the flow to be like below picture

[image]

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hi, I have inserted my code above. Please take a loog, if you need anything, let me know.